# sql "like" search inside javascript array or php array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

i've an array with names of city
`var names = {"john","johnny","nash","roni","ron"};`
now i want to use the feature of mysql `like` with it, just like google does, when suppose user typed `j` i want to return `"john","johnny"`, how to implement this, what i tried was returning `"john"` only when i type `"john"`

`

```
$('#student_name').keyup(function(){
    var name = $('#student_name').val();
    $('#suggestion').text(findStu(name,names));
});
    function findStu(val,obj){
        var arr,name;
        for(var i in obj){
            if(typeof obj[i] === "object" && obj[i] instanceof Array){
            arr = obj[i];
            arr.forEach(function(a){
            if(a === val) name = i;
            });
        }
    }
    return name;
}
```

`

Comment: Probably want to use contains. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains Are you going to need to use Wildcards. You could also look into an autocomplete lib if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the js prototype `.filter()`.

It maps the array, and returns elements based on a true/false statement. Then you could perform a basic string search with `indexOf()`.

It would work like this:

```
var filtered = names.filter(function(str) {
  return str.indexOf(str_to_search) != -1;
});
```

This would give you a filtered array containing only the names that matched the `str_to_search` variable.

[**MDN Array.prototype.filter Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

See it working in the snippet bellow:

```js
var names = ["john","johnny","nash","roni","ron"];

var str_to_search = 'j';

var filtered = names.filter(function(str) {
  return str.indexOf(str_to_search) != -1;
});

alert(filtered);
```